# I want a UIswitch to stay on whatever the user changes it to

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiswitch

My `UIswitch` is used to turn off the sound in my app. My problem is that my switch won't stay off if the user switches it to off. The switch is in another viewcontroller but same file. How do i make the switch stay off when the user selects it.

```
-(void)None{

    [player stop];
    [player1 stop];
    Volume.on=NO;

}

(IBAction)Volumeswitch:(id)sender {

    if(Volume.on){

        Label.text = @"On";

        Sounds=YES;

    }
    else{

        Label.text = @"Off";

        Sounds=NO;

        SoundTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.0001 target:self selector:@selector(None) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    }

}
```

Comment: save its state _before_ the and view controller released and restore back _after_ the view controller is loaded again. that is the procedure of how _any_ data can be 'remembered'.

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to say

Comment: in that case you may need to learn the essentials about how to store permanently any data. :)

Answer (score 1):

Like Gutblender said, focus on the logic and if you don't want to use a global variable, you can use the NSUserDefaults to store the value of your 'switch'.

e.g Whenever the switch is set to On

```
NSUserDefaults *pref = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[pref setBool:YES forKey:@"sound_on"];
[pref synchronize];
```

and in your viewDidAppear:

```
NSUserDefaults *pref = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
BOOL switchOn = [pref boolForKey:@"sound_on"];

[self.yourSwitch setOn:switchOn animated:NO];
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest keeping a BOOL probably global or public in whatever class plays sound, or some centralized "system configuration" class. Make that BOOL the actual decision "do I play sound or not?", not the `UISwitch`.

Then, simply initialize the `UISwitch` with the value of that `BOOL`, and make the value of the `BOOL` change when the user changes the `UISwitch`.

Comment: I tried it and it did not work. The code i have will be up on the question

Comment: Also i have a problem where the switch won't stay off when i leave the viewcontroller

Comment: Did you read my answer at all? You shouldn't be so worried about the state of the switch, but of the actual logic. You can update the `UISwitch` in the `UIViewController`'s `viewDidAppear`.